# ¿Como hacer que un spinner cambie de activity?

Tags: android-studio

estoy realizando una aplicación la cual debe cambiar de activity mediante un spinner pero desconozco el código que debo utilizar, gracias de antemano a los que puedan responder la pregunta.

Comment: Si lo colocas lo que has intentado seria mas facil ayudarte, Los spiner tiene su evento `setOnItemSelectedListener` con el cual controlas lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Querida Igmer gracias por responder, ya tengo mi aplicacion finalizada.

Comment: Te sugiero agregar el código que realices para que la comunidad  en base a esto te ayude a revisar cual sería el problema y darte una solución y opción, revisa por favor [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya finalice la aplicación el código es el siguiente:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private Spinner spinner;
   private Spinner spinner2;
   private Spinner spinner3;
   private Spinner spinner4;
   private Spinner spinner5;
   private Spinner spinner6;
   private Spinner spinner7;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
           startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

       }

   });
   Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), XML.class);
           startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

       }

   });
       Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
       btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PDF.class);
               startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                           }

       });

       spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
       spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
       spinner4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
       spinner5 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
       spinner6 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
       spinner7 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner7);

       ArrayAdapter spinAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Primervol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

       ArrayAdapter spin2Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Segundovol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner2.setAdapter(spin2Adapter);

       ArrayAdapter spin3Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Tercervol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner3.setAdapter(spin3Adapter);

       ArrayAdapter spin4Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Cuartovol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner4.setAdapter(spin4Adapter);

       ArrayAdapter spin5Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner5.setAdapter(spin5Adapter);

       ArrayAdapter spin6Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner6.setAdapter(spin6Adapter);

       ArrayAdapter spin7Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       spinner7.setAdapter(spin7Adapter);

       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Primervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2010.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Primervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2010.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Primervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_2010.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Primervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2010.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });
       spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista2, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista2.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Segundovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2011.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista2.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Segundovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2011.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista2.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Segundovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_2011.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista2.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Segundovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2011.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });

       spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista3, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista3.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Tercervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2012.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista3.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Tercervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2012.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista3.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Tercervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_201.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista3.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Tercervol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2012.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });
       spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista4, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista4.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Cuartovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2013.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista4.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Cuartovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2013.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista4.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Cuartovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_2013.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista4.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Cuartovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2013.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista4.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 5")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Cuartovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM5_2013.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });
       spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista5, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista5.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2014.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista5.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2014.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista5.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_2014.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista5.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2014.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista5.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 5")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM5_2014.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista5.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 6")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Quintovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM6_2014.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });
       spinner6.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista6, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista6.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2015.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista6.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2015.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista6.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_2015.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista6.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2015.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista6.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 5")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM5_2015.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista6.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 6")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sextovol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM6_2015.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });
       spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> lista7, View view, int pos, long id) {
               if (lista7.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 1")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM1_2016.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista7.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 2")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM2_2016.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista7.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 3")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM3_2016.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista7.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 4")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM4_2016.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista7.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 5")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM5_2016.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
               if (lista7.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("Num 6")){
                   ArrayAdapter listaAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.Sepvol,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUM6_2016.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });



   }
}
```

Espero este código sea de utilidad para alguien en el futuro